# sql server pivot 2 values

Tags: sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to get 2 values into a single line.

Example Data:

```
recipeID    componentID count
9           21          5
12          3           1
12          30          1
12          34          1
12          96          1
27          29          1
27          43          1
28          29          1
28          44          1
```

I have tried 2 pivots, but I get

```
recipeID   1    2    3    4     11   12   13   14
9          21   NULL NULL NULL  5    NULL NULL NULL
12         NULL NULL NULL 96    NULL NULL NULL 1
12         NULL NULL 34   NULL  NULL NULL 1    NULL
12         NULL 30 NULL   NULL  NULL 1    NULL NULL
12         3    NULL NULL NULL  1    NULL NULL NULL
27         NULL 43 NULL   NULL  NULL 1    NULL NULL
27         29   NULL NULL NULL  1    NULL NULL NULL
28         NULL 44 NULL   NULL  NULL 1    NULL NULL
28         29   NULL NULL NULL  1    NULL NULL NULL
```

When I would prefer:

```
recipeID   1    2    3    4     11   12   13   14
9          21   NULL NULL NULL  5    NULL NULL NULL
12         3    30   34   96    1    1    1    1
27         29   43 NULL   NULL  1    1    NULL NULL
28         29   44 NULL   NULL  1    1    NULL NULL
```

Any ideas?

Current code is:

```
select * from (
SELECT [recipeID]
      ,[componentID]
      ,[count]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [recipeID] order by ComponentID) rn
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [recipeID] order by ComponentID)+10 rn10
FROM [Recipe_Ingredients] ri_ ) as ri
PIVOT
(
sum([componentID])
for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as pvt
PIVOT
(
sum([count])
for rn10 in ([11],[12],[13],[14])) as pvt10
```

Comment: what exactly 1,2,3,4 ,11,12 etc when you have count of only 5,1

Comment: the counts are unique column names for the count and the items. 4 is the maximum amount of items in a recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregate function (sum or max) on the columns in the outer query together with a `group by` as usual:

```
SELECT 
    recipeID
    , SUM([1]) [1]
    , SUM([2]) [2]
    , SUM([3]) [3]
    , SUM([4]) [4]
    , SUM([11]) [11]
    , SUM([12]) [12]
    , SUM([13]) [13]
    , SUM([14]) [14]
FROM (
SELECT [recipeID]
      ,[componentID]
      ,[count]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [recipeID] order by ComponentID) rn
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [recipeID] order by ComponentID)+10 rn10
FROM [Recipe_Ingredients] ri_ ) as ri
PIVOT
(
sum([componentID])
for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as pvt
PIVOT
(
sum([count])
for rn10 in ([11],[12],[13],[14])) as pvt10
GROUP BY recipeID;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1a3c/1) and result:

```
| recipeID |  1 |      2 |      3 |      4 | 11 |     12 |     13 |     14 |
|----------|----|--------|--------|--------|----|--------|--------|--------|
|        9 | 21 | (null) | (null) | (null) |  5 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       12 |  3 |     30 |     34 |     96 |  1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
|       27 | 29 |     43 | (null) | (null) |  1 |      1 | (null) | (null) |
|       28 | 29 |     44 | (null) | (null) |  1 |      1 | (null) | (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do the magic.

```
select recipeID, 
  MAX([1]) AS '1', 
  MAX([2]) AS '2',
  MAX([3]) AS '3',
  MAX([4]) AS '4',
  MAX([11]) AS '11',
  MAX([12]) AS '12',
  MAX([13]) AS '13',
  MAX([14]) AS '14'
from (
SELECT [recipeID]
      ,[componentID]
      ,[count]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [recipeID] order by ComponentID) rn
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [recipeID] order by ComponentID) + 10 rn10
FROM [Recipe_Ingredients] ri_ ) as ri
PIVOT
(
sum([componentID])
for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as pvt
PIVOT
(
sum([count])
for rn10 in ([11],[12],[13],[14])) as pvt10
GROUP BY recipeId
```

Here you have a [Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79ff0c/7)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to do each pivot as a subselect, then union them together:

```
SELECT  Pivot1.recipeID ,
        Pivot1.[1] ,
        Pivot1.[2] ,
        Pivot1.[3] ,
        Pivot1.[4] ,
        Pivot2.[11] ,
        Pivot2.[12] ,
        Pivot2.[13] ,
        Pivot2.[14]
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      ( SELECT    [recipeID] ,
                                [componentID] ,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [recipeID] ORDER BY componentID ) rn
                      FROM      [Recipe_Ingredients] ri_
                    ) AS ri PIVOT
( SUM([componentID]) FOR rn IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4] ) ) AS pvt
        ) Pivot1
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
                     FROM   ( SELECT    [recipeID] ,
                                        [count] ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [recipeID] ORDER BY componentID )
                                        + 10 rn10
                              FROM      [Recipe_Ingredients] ri_
                            ) AS ri PIVOT
( SUM([count]) FOR rn10 IN ( [11], [12], [13], [14] ) ) AS pvt10
                   ) Pivot2 ON Pivot2.recipeID = Pivot1.recipeID
```

The occurs because the PIVOT function works off all the fields in the table being pivoted.  I explain this with an example in my [blog post here](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/the-sql-server-pivot-function/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c651/3/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(2000) = '',
        @sql2 VARCHAR(2000) = '',
        @sql3 VARCHAR(2000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    recipeID' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), RN) + ' THEN componentID END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(RN) + CHAR(10)
FROM(   
    SELECT DISTINCT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY recipeID ORDER BY componentID)
    FROM tbl    
)b

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), RN + 10) + ' THEN [count] END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(RN) + CHAR(10)
FROM(   
    SELECT DISTINCT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY recipeID ORDER BY componentID)
    FROM tbl    
)b

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY recipeID ORDER BY componentID)
    FROM tbl
)t
GROUP BY recipeID'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

**Result**

```
recipeID    1           2           3           4           11          12          13          14
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
9           21          NULL        NULL        NULL        5           NULL        NULL        NULL
12          3           30          34          96          1           1           1           1
27          29          43          NULL        NULL        1           1           NULL        NULL
28          29          44          NULL        NULL        1           1           NULL        NULL
```